# How to disable a html link to instead call a JS function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Having a text with annotations linking my text to dbpedia, I wanted to know if an effective way exists in Javascript for, by clicking on the link, to display a div with selected dbpedia information, rather than arriving on the page on the link ?
I am looking for some kind of "display none" on the link to allow me to display my div. I can not find this method, does it exist?

Furthermore, the links in my text are generated dynamically thanks to an Ajax request, and that they do not have id or class.

Here is one of my links in my text:

```
<a href="http://dbpedia.org/resource/Lorem_ipsum" title="http://dbpedia.org/resource/Lorem_ipsum" target="_blank" on>Lorem Ipsum</a>
```

Comment: So if the links are generated dynamically what is stopping you from adding a class or an event listener? This would make things much easier to ensure your function will only be triggered for the expected anchor tags

Comment: Depending how you create your dynamic anchor tags you can also add the even listener/calls like this. I have added two methods as some people write elements as a string rather than using `.createElement()` [**JsFiddle Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/dzst74cs/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the links are dynamically created you should use [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) to get them. You can use an [attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) to look only for links that start with a particular substring. Then use `preventDefault` to disable the link prior to using AJAX to grab the information and add it to a modal.

```
$(document).on('click', 'a[href^="http://dbpedia.org"]', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  // load data from your source

});
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/6uew4s5y/1/)**

The non-jQuery version would look something like this:

```
document.addEventListener('click', handleClick, false);

function handleClick(e) {
  const el = e.target;
  if (el.tagName === 'A' && el.href.startsWith('http://dbpedia.org')) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // Do things
  }
}
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/1zho4v6g/1/)**